# How to display character as a string from the displayboard?

Tags: c++, string, output

I am having problems in displaying the character as a string which I have set on my board. How do i display out my character from the board like a string.For example, when I input AABBA , the output will show AABBA as a string using the design i have set on my board for A and B.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring> 

using namespace std ;

void display(int dimI , int dimJ, const char A[20][40])
{
    for (int i =0 ; i < dimI ; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < dimJ ; ++j)
        {
            cout << A[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }
}
void clearScreen();
void delay() ;

int main()
{

    const int dimI = 20, dimJ = 40;
    string letter ;
    string displayboard(int dimI , int dimJ, const char A[20][40]) ;

    cout << "Please enter a word or number:";   
    getline(cin, letter);


    for(int i=0; i<letter.length(); ++i)
    {

    switch(letter[i])                          
    {

    case 'A' :
    {

    char board_A[dimI][dimJ] =
       {
             {' ' , ' ' , '#' , ' ' , ' ' },
             {' ' , '#' , ' ' , '#' , ' ' },
             {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
             {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
             {'#' , '#' , '#' , '#' , '#' },
             {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
             {'#' , ' ' , ' ' ,' '  , '#' }
        };

    display(dimI,dimJ,board_A);
    break ;
    }

     case 'B'  :
    {

     char board_B[dimI][dimJ] =
       {
             {'#' , '#' , '#' , '#' , ' ' },
             {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
             {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
             {'#' , '#' , '#' , '#' , ' ' },
             {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
             {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
             {'#' , '#' , '#' ,'#'  , ' ' }
       };
       display(dimI,dimJ,board_B);
       break ;
    }

void display( string displayboard [20][40] ,int dimI , int dimJ )
{

    for (int i =0 ; i< dimI ; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j, dimJ ; ++j)
        {
            cout << displayboard[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl ;
    }
    delay();
    clearScreen();
}

void delay()  
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000000000 ; ++i) ;
}

void clearScreen() 
{
    system("cls");
}
```

I expect the output to be AABBA as a string and display it horizontally.When i run my program,it only display it as an individual letter instead of a string whereby the characters are side by side.
Other than that, I am also thinking about making a loop so that the characters are able to scroll upwards and downwards,and left to right,making it look like a wrap around effect.

Comment: Aron, your code has compilation errors.

When I fixed those, the program roughly did the right thing as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have edited the post as  i have misinterpret the question.When i run my whole program,I wanted it to display like a string instead of an individual character.

Comment: I am able to display it as an individual character.

Comment: are you translating your speech through something,  it sounds strange?

Comment: nope.It's just that my English is not that good

Answer (score 0):

Your program tries to print letter-by-letter.
But for the desired giant string output you need to print pixel-line-by-pixel-line.

I.e. do not print "A" then "B".
Instead print

```
first  line A     first  line B ...
second line A     second line B ...
third  line A     third  line B ... 
fourth line A     fourth line B ...
```

```
print __#__  print ####_ newline
print _#_#_  print #___# newline
print #___#  print #___# newline
print #___#  print ####_ newline
print #####  print #___# newline
print #___#  print #___# newline
print #___#  print ####_ newline
```

I.e. you need to be aware of the whole string all the time and print parts of each letter in that string on each pixel line and only then print a single newline.

Answer (score 0):

as per @Yunnosch sir's answer you have to implement code may like below.

[Show here](https://repl.it/repls/WanAchingOperatingsystem)

Your Display mathod:

```
void display(string letter)
{
  const int dimI = 20, dimJ = 40;
  char board_A[dimI][dimJ] =
                   {
                         {' ' , ' ' , '#' , ' ' , ' ' },
                         {' ' , '#' , ' ' , '#' , ' ' },
                         {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
                         {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
                         {'#' , '#' , '#' , '#' , '#' },
                         {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
                         {'#' , ' ' , ' ' ,' '  , '#' }
                    };

char board_B[dimI][dimJ] =
                   {
                         {'#' , '#' , '#' , '#' , ' ' },
                         {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
                         {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
                         {'#' , '#' , '#' , '#' , ' ' },
                         {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
                         {'#' , ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , '#' },
                         {'#' , '#' , '#' ,'#'  , ' ' }
                   };
                  for (int i =0 ; i< dimI ; ++i)
                  {                       
                        for(int k=0; k<letter.length(); ++k)
                        {

                              switch(letter[k])                          
                                {
                                    case 'A' :
                                            { 
                                              cout<<board_A[i];              
                                              break;
                                            }   

                                    case 'B'  :                    
                                            {
                                              cout<<board_B[i]; 
                                              break;
                                            }
                                }                                  


                      }
                      cout<<endl;
                  }

 }
```