# lang-c Print two pyramids with space in between using nested for loops and function?

Tags: c, function, cs50

lang-c Output should look like following:

```
   #  #
  ##  ##
 ###  ###
####  ####
```

But my problem is i have functions called `rightPyramid(num_rows)` which has the code:

```
void rightPyramid(int num_rows)
{
    for(int row =1; row<=num_rows; row++){
        for(int col=1; col<=row; col++ ){
            printf("#");
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

output for `rightPyramid(num_rows)`:

```
#
##
###
####
```

and code for `leftPyramid(num_rows)` is:

```
void leftPyramid(int num_rows)
{
    for (int i = 1; i<=num_rows; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=num_rows-i; j++){
            printf(" ");
            }
        for(int k= 1; k<=i; k++){
            printf("#");
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

output for `leftPyramid(num_rows)`:

```
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

Is there anyway to manipulate both functions to output:

```
   #  #
  ##  ##
 ###  ###
####  ####
```

Comment: No there is not. The moment you print a newline, you lost your chance to print something else on that line. Write a single function that does `for (...) { for (...) {putchar('#');} putchar(' '); for (...) {putchar('#');} }`

Comment: If you want to split this up into separate functions, you could have two functions that take the row number and number of rows, one that prints the left part of just that row, the other prints just the right part of that row. Then you can call those two functions in a loop.

Comment: Both comments in my opinion qualify as answers. Even without additional explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037580/how-to-display-character-as-a-string-from-the-displayboard/58038015#58038015

Comment: Thank You all, i just wanted to know of the possibility. I'll try to make it as how -Barmar suggested.

Comment: @Barmar can you put that comment as answer so  i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having functions that print the entire pyramids, write functions that just print one row of each pyramid. Then you can call the functions for the left and right portions of the row in a loop.

```
void leftPyramidRow(int num_rows, int row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < num_rows - row; col++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < row; col++) {
        printf("#");
    }
}

void rightPyramidRow(int row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < row; col++) {
        printf("#");
    }
}

void pyramid(int num_rows) {
    for (int row = 1; row <= num_rows; row++) {
        leftPyramidRow(num_rows, row);
        printf("  ");
        rightPyramidRow(row);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```